# convert int to pointer int *ptr position;

Tags: c++

i have 5 digits in 1 pointer

```
int* reversevec(int* ptr, unsigned int Ne){
  int* ReverResult;
  unsigned int rever=Ne, z;
  ReverResult=(int*)malloc(Ne*sizeof(int));
  for (int i = 0; i < Ne; ++i)
  {
    z=*(ptr+rever);
    
    printf("%i ",z);//to be sure z starts from the last number on ptr to the fisrt
    rever--;
  }
  return ReverResult;
}
```

example
Number of elements(Ne)=5

int* ptr have 5 numbers {1 2 3 4 5}

every time when z is printed i got {5 4 3 2 1}

but i cant save z into *ReverResult

`ReverResult=(z+rever);`

> this line is what i tried to put into cicle for to save z and position into int pointer ReverResult but i cant convert int to int*;

Comment: Note that `ptr+rever` is one past array and thus out of bounds in very first loop run, so undefined behaviour. You need to decrement before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems here

`z` is a local variable int.
its address will not be useful to return, because it will be out of scope.
returning an offset from its address is even worse, since that is a totally unrelated place in memory.

you also have an off-by-one error. imagine Number elements is one. You will then try to view ptr+1 instead of ptr+0.

you've also tagged this c++ but are writing c style code.

to answer your primary question, rather than writing  `ReverResult=(z+rever)` one could write `*(ReverResult + rever - 1) = *(ptr + i)`

Comment: *'c style code'* – oh, and reinventing the wheel, there's [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) already...

Comment: quite right @Aconcagua but I think it's probably a homework question despite asker failing to mention it is a homework question, thus they'd be unable to use std::reverse

Answer (score 0):

The other way round, you need to dereference your pointer to be able to assign. After all, you are easier off with pure pointer arithmetics:

```
int* result = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * ne);
// let's just have to pointers running through the two arrays:
for(int* p = ptr + ne, *r = result; p-- != ptr; ++r)
{
    *r = *p;
//  ^    ^  this is the important part: dereference both pointers
}
```

If you still prefer indices you can use `operator[]`:

```
--ne; // so that we don't have to subtract within the loop again and again
for(size_t index = 0; index <= ne; ++index)
{
    result[index] = ptr[ne - index];
//        ^^^^^^^ again: dereferencing, this time with offset
}
```

`array[index]` is entirely equivalent to `*(array + index)` – and actually it, too, to `index[array]` (e. g. `7[array]`), which is often used to fool the inexperienced...